# name is not defined during an import

Tags: python, maya

i'm facing a problem I can't understand...
here is a part of an initial code for an auto-rig :

```
def Legs():
    Vleg = cmds.intSliderGrp('legs', q=True ,v=True)
    if Vleg == 1:
        Leg01 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg1', l= 'Sym. Limb no.1', min=0, max=8, f=True)
    elif Vleg == 2:
        Leg01 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg1', l= 'Sym. Limb no.1', min=0, max=8, f=True)
        Leg02 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg2', l= 'Sym. Limb no.2', min=0, max=8, f=True)
    elif Vleg == 3:
        Leg01 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg1', l= 'Sym. Limb no.1', min=0, max=8, f=True)
        Leg02 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg2', l= 'Sym. Limb no.2', min=0, max=8, f=True)
        Leg03 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg3', l= 'Sym. Limb no.3', min=0, max=8, f=True)
    else :
        Leg01 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg1', l= 'Sym. Limb no.1', min=0, max=8, f=True)
        Leg02 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg2', l= 'Sym. Limb no.2', min=0, max=8, f=True)
        Leg03 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg3', l= 'Sym. Limb no.3', min=0, max=8, f=True)
        Leg04 = cmds.intSliderGrp('Leg4', l= 'Sym. Limb no.4', min=0, max=8, f=True)


win = 'win'
win = cmds.window(win, s=True, t = 'Auto-rig Prototype')
cmds.showWindow(win)
cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.intSliderGrp ('legs', l = 'Number of symetrical parts', min=1, max=4, v=1, f=True)
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.text(l='please execute commands in the APPROPRIATE order')
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.button (l = '1 : Set', c = 'Legs()')
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.button (l = '2 : Create Guides', c = 'Guide()')
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.button( l= '3 : Set Rig', c= 'rig()')
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.button( l= '4 : Set CTRLS', c= 'ctrl()')
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.button( l= '5 : Parent CTRLS', c= 'Par()')
cmds.separator(h = 5 )
cmds.button (l = 'Delete selection and unused nodes', c = 'Suppr()')
```

When i run this scirpt alone, eveything works as expected, but then i tried to import it

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
def printNewMenuItem( item ):
    if item == 'Arachnoid':
        if cmds.window(InitWin, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(InitWin)
        import SpidRig
    else :
        print str(item) + ' : this command is not scripted yet'
InitWin = cmds.window(t='Choose your rig')
if cmds.window(InitWin, exists = True):
    cmds.deleteUI(InitWin)
cmds.window(t='Choose your rig')
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.optionMenu( label='Rig Type', changeCommand=printNewMenuItem)
cmds.menuItem( label='Basic Humanoid' )
cmds.menuItem( label='Arachnoid' )
cmds.menuItem( label='Bird' )
cmds.showWindow( InitWin )
```

And now, depending on times, either the window ' Auto-rig Prototype' never opens, either it returns me this error :

```
# Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 1: name 'Legs' is not defined #
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure where you think you're importing `Legs` exactly…?!

Comment: i import it from the file SpidRig, so when i select Arachnoid, it is supposed to close 'Choose your rig', open 'Auto-rig Prototype' then it should work with the SpidRig.py file.

(i know my explainations are a bit confused, but i'm confused myself too, i started using python 2-3 months ago.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove the string from your commands :

```
cmds.button (l = '1 : Set', c = Legs)
```

and write your command like so :

```
def Legs(*args):
    Vleg = cmds.intSliderGrp('legs', q=True ,v=True)
    ...
```

run from a fresh maya restarted and then, we will be able to debug.
It seems to be a problem of namespace / import / global  var and local var

like this error :

```
# Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 1: name 'Legs' is not defined #
```

it means that when you click on this button :

```
cmds.button (l = '1 : Set', c = 'Legs()')
```

it tries to exec this litteral command. But, zhen you import it like so :

```
import leg_script
```

you import it with a namespace : `leg_script`
for example, if you import like this :

```
import leg_script as leg
```

the namespace is : `leg`

in this two case you Leg proc is now written literally `leg_script.Leg()` or `leg.Leg()`

You could get rid of the namespace  by using :

```
from leg_script import *
```

but this is a bad practice beacause to debug your script it will become really difficult.

---

So to recap the problem, when you write litteral strings in command :

```
cmds.button (l = '1 : Set', c = 'Legs()')
```

your script as problems with imports, if you want to ignore namespace problems :

```
cmds.button (l = '1 : Set', c = Legs)
```

which is the way to go, otherwise you would havve to write the namespace in the string :

```
cmds.button (l = '1 : Set', c = 'leg_script.Legs()')
```

but it wont work in local and futhermore, only if it is called with this namespace.... so dont do it !